# Can we generate auto date in SQL, if date is not exit in table with zero value in table?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a table with the name of final_registration where I am storing registration data, Following is my table:

```
*---------------------------------------------------------------*
| id | event_id |   Name  |   booking_date      | ticket_status |
*---------------------------------------------------------------*
| 1  |    101   | Sandeep | 2018-11-30 15:43:24 |    active     | 
| 2  |    101   | Jagveer | 2018-12-01 18:44:20 |    active     |
| 3  |    101   | Sudhir  | 2018-12-01 20:34:20 |    active     |
| 4  |    101   | Aman    | 2018-12-03 18:44:20 |    active     |
*---------------------------------------------------------------*
```

I am runing following query for output:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), booking_date 
 FROM final_registration 
 WHERE `event_id` = 101 
 AND `booking_date` >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
 AND ticket_status='active' 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`booking_date`, '%d-%b');
```

The output is showing:

```
*--------------------------*
| count(id) | booking_date |
*--------------------------*
|     2     |  2018-12-01  |
|     1     |  2018-12-03  |
*--------------------------*
```

But I do not want  this, I want the following output from the query:

```
*--------------------------*
| count(id) | booking_date |
*--------------------------*
|     2     |  2018-12-01  |
|     0     |  2018-12-02  |
|     1     |  2018-12-03  |
|     0     |  2018-12-04  |
*--------------------------*
```

Note Today is 4th Dec-2018 so here, I am using the current date.

so how can I generate auto date if there is no date in my table values?

Comment: outer join a calendar table.

Comment: how can I join a calendar table, means should I create a calendar table? sorry, I am new in SQL?

Comment: Yes, create a calendar table that stores all needed dates. (Pretty handy to have available.)

Comment: @jarlh can you provide some links or references for calendar table?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a loop starting at current date and then populating a table if a value exist.

Obviously you'll have to think about stopping the loop though, like maybe check if the
last entry of your table has the current date of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, then as @jarlh said above, you better get a calendar table and just join your table with it. There is a bunch of stuff on the net where you can get that. 2nd option, I can suggest, is that, unless you want to create a table, is to write an excel table with the dates and a simple id at the start and in next column can be the actual dates with a format of your own choosing. Then, right click on your database name on ssms object explorer and use import data. You don’t have to go through creating a table, you can import the excel file into your database. Then just join the tables.

Comment: Oh! You want to group by date and count the number of event id on that date. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, right. I want to group by date, but if there is no date like I have 1-Dec but not for 2-Dec then it shows count 0 for 2-Dec.

Comment: Well, then as @jarlh said above, you better get a calendar table and just join your table with it. There is a bunch of stuff on the net where you can get that.

Comment: can I get any reference or link? so that I can create a calendar table in my database.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/. Might want to format a bit

Comment: I have created the calendar table and try to run this 

SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL(COUNT(final_registration.id), 0) AS total_count FROM final_registration RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(final_registration.booking_date) = calendar.datefield) WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(booking_date)) FROM final_registration) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(booking_date)) FROM final_registration)) AND final_registration.event_id = 101 AND final_registration.booking_date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') GROUP BY DATE

Comment: SELECT CT.DATE, COUNT(YT.EVENTID) FROM CALENDARTABLE AS CT LEFT JOIN YOURTABLE AS YT ON CT.DATE=YT.REGISTRATIONDATE A query like this should be working (might want to add group by and what not). Basically, try to get all the dates from your calendar table and join with your table on the matching dates. The number of the matches on a date should give you the number of events on that day and if there is no date, then it is 0, meaning there is no even on that date.